# Visual Studio 2013 View has an unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I want to add a database project to the solution, but database references to other databases, that i do not want to include in solution.

The visual studio collects 84 errors.

I thought that, the easiest solution is ignoring build errors and warning to this database project, but i did not find and solution.

Is Database project useless, if i develope a lot of applications with lot of databases, that are in relation somewhere?

What can I do now?

Comment: Why have references in one database to another database but not want them in the solution?

Comment: I have answered this question, read below.

Comment: @Kyle-Hale Probably the referenced database already exists, and they don't have the option of recreating it with SSDT. I suspect this is the *likeliest* scenario in the real (outside of Microsoft labs) world.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is extract a dacpac of those referenced databases and indclude them as DB references. You won't attempt to build/publish them by default, but they will let you continue.

I had to use SQLPackage.exe to extract the dacpac as I couldn't always do it through the SSMS or VS interfaces if there were many dependencies. I wrote up my process on my blog:
http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

Comment: I have tried to create dacpac file by Extract Data-Tier Application  command in SQL Management Studio, but its failed and showed an error window, that contains similar lot of error messages than the Question Title: "View has an unresolved reference to object". Are you sure, there is no other option than referencing every databases by database reference? There are lot of referencing databases, it can take a few hours to reference them... :(

Comment: Adding the references doesn't take too long. Put them in a place the project can see (same folder or a "shared" folder above all of your projects) and add a DB reference pointing to the file - same server, different database, don't use anything in the "variable name" part.  You'll probably need to create it from the SQLPackage command line (see above blog post for an example of how to do that). Should take a couple of minutes to generate the dacpacs and a minute or two to add each DB reference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to simply BUILD the "referenced" Database project in the Visual Studio solution. The issue appears to be related to when using references from one database project to another and the referenced database project has changed and not been built recently. VS seems to keep an internal reference based on the "built" database project rather than the current version of the source. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, for me, was to reference the other database project using **References > Add Database Reference...**.

Under **Database Location > Database variable**, ensure that this is blanked out.  You want the *Example usage:* section to look like how you're using it.

This will add a reference with a *DatabaseVariableLiteralValue* instead of *DatabaseSqlCmdVariable* to the project.

This can also be done using a dacpac or system database (eg master).